# how to use <lightning:input type="search"/> to search users?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lookup

I am currently using `c:CustomLookup` to search users in the below code but I am looking to use lookup search(`<lightning:input type="search"/>`) because `c:CustomLookup` reqires some more efforts like I need to fetch value of the user separately while saving the record.

```
<aura:component controller="SampleClass">
<aura:attribute name="newJenJob" type="RM_Configuration__c"/>
    <div aura:id="jenUserCrtModal" class="slds-hide">
        <div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <div class="align-align--absolute-center">Create Jenkins User</div>
                    <div aura:id="jenUserErrorMsgId" style="color:red;" class="slds-hide slds-align--absolute-center">Please fill all the Mandatory Fields *</div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content" style="padding:20px;">
                            <lightning:input name="n1" label="Jenkins User Name" value="{!v.newJenUser.Jenkins_User_Name__c}" required="true"/>
                            <lightning:input name="n2" type="password" value="{!v.newJenUser.Jenkins_Password__c}" label="Jenkins User Password" required="true"/>
                            <!--<force:inputField value="{!v.newJenUser.SFDC_User__c}" required="true"/>-->                             
                            <c:CustomLookup aura:id="jenUsrId" objectAPIName="User" IconName="standard:goals" selectedRecord="{!v.selectedJenUsrLookUpRecord}" label="SFDC User"/>                          
                            <lightning:input name="n5" label="Is Active?" type="checkbox" value="{!v.newJenUser.Jenkins_User_Active__c}" checked="{!v.newJenUser.Jenkins_User_Active__c}"/>
               </div>
               <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <div class="align-align--absolute-center">
                        <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.closeModal}" class="cancelBtnStyl"/>
                        <lightning:button label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveJenUser}" class="saveBtnStyl"/>
                    </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>           
    </div>
<aura:component>
```

Can anyone please let me know how to do that?

Comment: please share what you have tried alongside your specific problem, show a minimum level of effort before posting. additionally, take some time to read [Ask] and take the [tour] and update your post accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @Himanshu, I have put the things what I am trying, Can you please tell me whether it is possible in this way or not.

Answer (score 8):

I think you have mistaken `<lightning:input type="search"/>` as a standard lookup component.

It is a mere input control, which when defined as `type = "search"` will just display the Lightning Design System search utility icon.

Refer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) for documentation

You will have to build a custom lookup field to achieve this. Hence custom code would be required

Here are a few examples which will help you in creating the lookup component.

- [Example 1](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-lightning-inputlookup-missing-component.html)
- [Example 2](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/lookup-component-in-salesforce-lightning/)
- [Example 3](http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/01/07/custom-lookup-lightning-component/)

Comment: Great answer! another option is to use [Strike Lookup](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeLookup) from the strike library - very recommended!!!